how to unnest json string from data frame in R?
Hi and thanks for reading me. I have a data frame that have the next structure:
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  customerId transactionHistory                                                                                          
       <dbl> <chr>                                                                                                       
1      40895 [{'transactionId': 0, 'date': '2024-05-04', 'status': 'SUCCESSFUL', 'transactionAmount': '$40.00'}, {'trans…
2      42966 [{'transactionId': 0, 'date': '2024-05-21', 'status': 'SUCCESSFUL', 'transactionAmount': '$40.00'}, {'trans…
3      51806 [{'transactionId': 0, 'date': '2024-04-22', 'status': 'SUCCESSFUL', 'transactionAmount': '$40.00'}, {'trans…
4      53366 [{'transactionId': 0, 'date': '2024-05-23', 'status': 'SUCCESSFUL', 'transactionAmount': '$40.00'}, {'trans…
5      53632 [{'transactionId': 0, 'date': '2024-04-24', 'status': 'SUCCESSFUL', 'transactionAmount': '$40.00'}, {'trans…
6      53871 [{'transactionId': 0, 'date': '2024-04-18', 'status': 'SUCCESSFUL', 'transactionAmount': '$40.00'}]   

And I want to unnest the data to be able on get a bigger table with all the transactions in a properly data frame format, but I dont be able to find a way to do that, because the transactionHistory column is a string, not a json.
Does anyone knows a way to do that?

What's the data source and how exactly are you importing? It just feels a bit like a XY-problem . Are you by any chance trying to parse Javascript?

Here is one possible approach which first replace single quotes in the JSON string by double quotes (see Single vs double quotes in JSON), then uses lapply and jsonlite::fromJSON to convert to a data.frame and finally unnests the column of transaction histories.
Using a minified reproducible example:
dat <- tibble::tibble(
  customerId = c(40895, 42966),
  transactionHistory = c(
    "[{'transactionId': 0, 'date': '2024-05-04', 'status': 'SUCCESSFUL', 'transactionAmount': '$40.00'}, {'transactionId': 1, 'date': '2024-05-04', 'status': 'SUCCESSFUL', 'transactionAmount': '$40.00'}]",
    "[{'transactionId': 2, 'date': '2024-05-04', 'status': 'SUCCESSFUL', 'transactionAmount': '$40.00'}, {'transactionId': 3, 'date': '2024-05-04', 'status': 'SUCCESSFUL', 'transactionAmount': '$40.00'}]"
  )
)

dat
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   customerId transactionHistory                                                 
#>        <dbl> <chr>                                                              
#> 1      40895 [{'transactionId': 0, 'date': '2024-05-04', 'status': 'SUCCESSFUL'…
#> 2      42966 [{'transactionId': 2, 'date': '2024-05-04', 'status': 'SUCCESSFUL'…

library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(tidyr)
library(jsonlite)

dat |>
  mutate(
    # Replace ' by \"
    transactionHistory = gsub("\\'", "\"", transactionHistory),
    # Convert to dataframe
    transactionHistory = lapply(transactionHistory, jsonlite::fromJSON)
  ) |>
  tidyr::unnest(transactionHistory)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   customerId transactionId date       status     transactionAmount
#>        <dbl>         <int> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>            
#> 1      40895             0 2024-05-04 SUCCESSFUL $40.00           
#> 2      40895             1 2024-05-04 SUCCESSFUL $40.00           
#> 3      42966             2 2024-05-04 SUCCESSFUL $40.00           
#> 4      42966             3 2024-05-04 SUCCESSFUL $40.00

